# guitar picking noise

Tags: acoustic-guitar, strumming, picks

Quick question! When I am strumming on my acoustic guitar and I record myself playing, I can easily hear my guitar pick. It almost sounds like when you mute all the strings and just strum but not quite as loud. I mostly use an Alice guitar pick that is 0.81 mm thick. Is it normal to hear the pick when strumming or is my pick holding technique off?

Answer (score 3):

Could be your technique, could be the microphone or microphone placement, guitar setup, string gauge, pick selection, and most likely some combination of all of those.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is about the sound of *a recording* of an acoustic guitar, if it is not clear how you recorded it in the first place as Todd suggested, it will be very difficult to help. I suggest you improve your question by adding more details.

In the meanwhile, you can check if you can find the freq. which is bothering you and trying to see if you can correct it a bit with eq.

My final guess is that the mic is probably too where you play with the pick + you play you're strumming too hard. Try playing *a little* softer and moving the mic away a bit, and see what happens.

One way of finding the desired sound when micing a recording is to move the mic around and listening through headphones. If you are doing all the job, that may be a little difficult, but you could try leaving the mic fixed and listening how various distances of the guitar to the mic affect the sound.

Hope this helps!